# Having to manually add a project reference to csproj file when creating Unit Tests

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing

I'm following [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/walkthrough-creating-and-running-unit-tests-for-managed-code?view=vs-2022) on how to create Unit Tests for my C# project. However when I'm attempting to import one project into another I get an error saying the type or namespace cannot be found. I was able to fix it by manually adding this to the csproj file of the unit tests project:

```
<ItemGroup>
<ProjectReference Include="..\MyNEAT\MyNEAT.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Is there a reason I'm having to do this (as the tutorial doesn't mention having to do this at all) and is there way I can create Unit Tests without having to do this every time?

Comment: You have to do it, but the IDE has a graphical way to do it. You needn't edit the file in a text editor.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I forgot to mention but I did try add one as a dependency of the other in the solution properties and it didn't change anything.

Comment: @Kronos you probably messed up that within the text editor, my recommendation. start over and use `Right click on your current project -> Add -> Reference -> Project -> solution -> choose the project` and click ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do it, but the IDE has a graphical way to do it. You needn't edit the file in a text editor.

[image: Add reference context menu]

And then select the Product:

[image: Select the project]

Do it in the correct direction:

1. Your Unit Test must reference your Product
2. Your Product must not reference the Unit Test